# Short-circuiting Java Optional.flatMap()

Tags: java, option-type

Here's an interesting quandary using Java's `Optional.flatMap()`. I have a class that encapsulates a [CURIE](https://www.w3.org/TR/curie/) in the form `"foo:bar"` or just `"bar"`. I also have a class for registering prefixes to namespaces, as well as for keeping track of the default namespace. It has a method `findNamespaceByPrefix()` returning an `Optional<URI>` (as the prefix may not be registered) and a method `getDefaultNamespace()`, also returning an `Optional<URI>` (as there may not be a default namespace).

Given some CURIE I want to find the namespace. It's tempting to use this:

```java
Optional<URI> namespace = curie.getPrefix()
    .flatMap(this::findNamespaceByPrefix)
    .or(this::getDefaultNamespace);
```

But that is wrong. The problem is that it returns the default namespace, even if there is a prefix but no namespace was associated with that prefix. We only want to get back the default namespace (if any) if there is no prefix indicated at all in the CURIE.

Here is a solution:

```java
Optional<String> prefix = curie.getPrefix();
Optional<URI> namespace = prefix.isPresent()
    ? prefix.flatMap(this::findNamespaceByPrefix)
    : getDefaultNamespace();
```

And I'm fine with that, but it strikes me as somewhat non-functional with its use of the ternary operator, and using `Optional.isPresent()` usually indicates there is a better way to do things.

Do any `Optional` experts have a better, more functional solution to "short-circuit" the flat mapping? (I have a hunch I could do something with several layers of wrapping and unwrapping `Optional` using `Optional:of` and `Optional:get` in the pipeline, but is there something perhaps more elegant?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of "flatMapping" you should keep your second level of optional:

```
Optional<URI> namespace = curie.getPrefix()
    .map(Application::findNamespaceByPrefix)
    .orElseGet(Application::getDefaultNamespace);
```

The `map` operation maps a prefix, if present, into a wrapped `Optional<Optional<URI>>` that is either empty (if the prefix is absent) or contains a `Optional<URI>` that is either empty (if no namespace could be found for the prefix) or contains the actual namespace.

And the outer `orElseGet` only gets called when the wrapping `Optional` is empty and your prefix is therefore absent.

Comment: Yes! That does it! I had a hunch I needed to keep the `Optional<Optional<URI>>`, but I was getting confused about how to get rid of it. I think this is the solution!

Comment: The problem is that `flatMap()` conflates two different reasons that the namespace could be missing. This solution separates out the two and doesn't confuse them.

Answer (score -1):

You check for null prefix

```
Optional<URI> namespace = prefix
   .filter(Objects::nonNull)
   .flatMap(this::findNamespaceByPrefix)
   .or(this::getDefaultNamespace);
```

you can test it as below:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test(Optional.ofNullable(null));
        test(Optional.ofNullable("yourprefix"));
    }

    private static void test(Optional<String> prefix) {
        Optional<URI> namespace2 = prefix
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .flatMap(p -> Optional.of(URI.create(p)))
                .or(() -> Optional.of(URI.create("default")));

        System.out.println(namespace2);
    }
```

Comment: What type is the variable `prefix` in your example? Is it of type `String`? Is it of type `Optional<String>`? Is it of type `Stream<String>`? Or something else?

Comment: @GarretWilson, it is `Optional<String> prefix = Optional.ofNullable("your prefix or null in case of not exists");`

Comment: How can you filter an `Optional` value by `Objects::nonNull`, when an `Optional` can never contain a `null` value? Isn't that a pointless operation to perform on an `Optional`?

Comment: @GarretWilson It must be `Optional<String>` for the code to compile, same as in the question. But still doesn't address the question, ignoring the first code block there.

Comment: yes, optional is a wrapper it can contain null values if it created as `Optional.ofNullable(null);`

Comment: No, `Optional.ofNullable(null)` will not contain a `null` value. It will not contain a value at all; it will be empty. If you don't believe me, try calling `Optional.ofNullable(null).get()`.

Comment: If you want you can test my code with `Optional<String> prefix = Optional.ofNullable(null);` and you will get your default executed.